# DefaultEquality Comparator in LINQ

Tags: .net, comparison

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<I> bars = new List<I>();
            bars.Add(new A() { Id = 1 });
            bars.Add(new B() { Id = 1 });
            bars.Add(new A() { Id = 1 });

            var distictBars = bars.Distinct();

            foreach (var item in distictBars)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    interface I
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class A : Base, I, IEquatable<A>
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.Id + "-A"; }
        }

        public bool Equals(A other)
        {
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is A)
                return this.Equals(obj as A);
            else
                return object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
        }
    }

    class B : Base, I, IEquatable<B>
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.Id + "-B"; }
        }

        public bool Equals(B other)
        {
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is A)
                return this.Equals(obj as A);
            else
                return object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is the following

```
1-A 
1-B 
1-A
```

I need however the following

```
1-A 
1-B
```

that is, eliminate the duplicates of type A or B. It seems that the `Distinct` LINQ method didn't take in consideration my Equals override, nor the IEquitable interface implementation.

How should I proceed in order than that method does the specified comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Distinct` method will likely use something similar to a `HashSet<T>` internally, which relies on a hash code (obviously). You will need to also override `GetHashCode`.

---

It seems to me you have some unnecessary duplication in general. Both your `A` and `B` classes share basically the same logic for determining equality; is what you want to ensure that two `Base` objects are equal if their IDs are equal *and* they are the same type? (This is what it looks like to me; your implementation seems to contain a couple of mistakes in this case, but that's still my best guess.)

If so, just make `Base` implement `IEquatable<Base>` and your `A` and `B` implementations become much simpler:

```
class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    public Base(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(Base other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Ensure As only compare equal with other As
        // and the same for Bs (and potentially other subtypes).
        return other.GetType().Equals(GetType()) && other.Id == Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is Base)
        {
            return Equals((Base)other);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}

class A : Base, I
{
    public A(int id) : base(id)
    { }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Id + "-A"; }
    }
}

class B : Base, I
{
    public B(int id) : base(id)
    { }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.Id + "-B"; }
    }
}
```

Notice that I also changed the setter on the `Id` property to `private`; in general, it's a very risky game to make a field or property publicly writable when it's used in the type's `GetHashCode` implementation (since if an object's hash code ever changes, it stops working as a key in a hashtable).

---

*This comment becomes unnecessary if you apply my recommendation above.*

Also, **warning!** It looks to me like you've got a risk of infinite recursion in your `B.Equals` method:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is A)
            // There is no method with the signature Equals(A);
            // so this will just call your Equals(object) method --
            // i.e., THIS method -- over and over again.
            return this.Equals(obj as A);
        else
            return object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
    }
```

Comment: override GetHashCode... what should I return there? The Id?

Comment: @serhio: Sure, that would work. As long as it never changes for a given object.

Comment: If two objects are equal, then GetHashCode() should return the same value.  Since ID is the only thing you're comparing, return this.ID.GetHashCode().  If you were comparing more, then xor all the comparison field's GetHashCode() values.

Comment: @mattmc3: Int32.GetHashCode() just returns the integer. @serhio: That's what I'm saying, isn't it? Your current implementation can go into an infinite recursive loop (which will overflow the stack).

Comment: So, need I implementing IEquatable<T> at all?

Comment: related this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981298/equals-vs-gethashcode-when-comparing-objects

Comment: @Dan Tao - The implementation of GetHashCode() is platform dependent and subject to change.  You should never depend on it returning a specific value - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx.

Comment: @mattmc3: Your link is referring to the `string.GetHashCode` method, not `int.GetHashCode`. However, that's really beside the point. What difference does it make whether the implementation of `int.GetHashCode` changes or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `.GetHashCode()` in your objects.  I suggest something like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return this.Id;
}
```