# Equals vs GetHashCode when comparing objects

Tags: .net, comparison, equals, gethashcode

Should we override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` properties when implementing a custom class instances comparison?

In the following code I have a collection of classes. The class `A` is compared by the **`ID`**, the class `B` - by **`Code`**.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<I> bars = new List<I>();
            bars.Add(new A() { Id = 1, Code = "one A" });
            bars.Add(new B() { Id = 1, Code = "one B" });
            bars.Add(new A() { Id = 1, Code = "one A+" });
            bars.Add(new B() { Id = 1, Code = "one B" }); // Code = "one B+"

            var distictBars = bars.Distinct();

            foreach (var item in distictBars)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Code);
            }
        }
    }

    interface I
    {
        string Code { get; set; }
    }

    class A : I, IEquatable<A>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(A other)
        {
            // this is the ??? comparison
            return this.Id == other.Id;
            //return this.Code == other.Code;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is A)
                return this.Equals(obj as A);
            else
                return object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // this is the wanted comparison
            return this.Id;
        }
    }

    class B : I, IEquatable<B>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(B other)
        {
            // this is the ??? comparison
            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is B)
                return this.Equals(obj as B);
            else
                return object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // this is the wanted comparison
            return this.Code.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
one A
one B
```

in case the commented `Code = "one B+"` the output is

```
one A
one B
one B+
```

Now I ask myself what for should I override the `Equals` in the `B` class if it seems that this have no effect on comparison?

Is `GetHasCode()` overriding sufficient for that kind of comparisons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have I implemented Equals()/GetHashCode() correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700099/have-i-implemented-equals-gethashcode-correctly)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's what you need to understand about the relationship between `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Hash codes are used by hashtables to quickly find a "bucket" in which an element is expected to exist. **If elements are in two different buckets, the assumption is they cannot be equal.**

The outcome of this is that you should view a hash code, for purposes of determining uniqueness, as a quick *negative* check: i.e., if two objects have different hash codes, they are *not* the same (regardless of what their `Equals` methods return).

If two objects have the *same* hash code, they will reside in the same bucket of a hash table. *Then* their `Equals` methods will be called to determine equality.

So `GetHashCode` *must* return the same value for two objects that you want to be considered equal.

Comment: Does that mean that different objects in the same bucket have the same HashCode?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin exactly. If you insert N objects with keys that yield the same HashCode into a Dictionary they will end up in the same bucket, that is, when trying to get any of these objects by key, you will end up enumerating the whole bucket in order to get the corresponding element for the provided key.

Comment: That's not precisely true; different objects in the same bucket have either the same HashCode or one that's considered sufficiently equivalent to it by the collection (usually modulo the number of buckets), because there are usually more possible hash codes than there are possible buckets.

Answer (score 8):

The `Distinct` method will use the `GetHashCode` method to determine inequality between the items, and the `Equals` method to determine equality.

It first make a fast comparison using the hash code to determine which items are definitely not equal, i.e. have different hash codes, then it compares the items that have the same hash code to determine which are really equal.

In your implementation of the `B` class you have an inconsistent implementation of the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method, so the comparison won't work properly. Your two `B` objects have different hash codes, so they won't be compared to each other. Two items that are considered to be equal should also return the same hash code.

If a class implements the `IEquatable<T>` interface, the `Equals(T)` method will be used, otherwise the `Equals(object)` method is used.

Answer (score 5):

You always need to override them *together* and with compatible implementations. A hash-code match/mismatch means (respectively) "*possible* equality" and "non-equality". The hash-code ***by itself*** does not indicate equality. Hence, after a hash-code match is found (or used to create groups of values), `Equals` is still checked to determine a match.

If the two do not agree, you might never find matches.