# Intersect between 2 collections in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections, intersect

I have:

```
            List<INFRAESTRUCTURA> l1 = listQ1.ToList();
            List<INFRAESTRUCTURA> l2 = listQ2.ToList();
```

And I need to intersect it comparing ids. Something like that:

```
 l1.Intersect(l2, l1[].id_infraestructura == l2[].id_infraestructura)
```

But I don't know which method I must use and it sintax.

I found this:

```
var ids = list1.Select(a => a.id).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.id));
```

But this return a list of ids and i need a list of elements contained in both lists.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the return here? `List<INFRAESTRUCTURA>`?

Comment: So the result is `List<INFRAESTRUCTURA>` with only those where the ID appears in both collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but you can use `Intersect` with your custom comparer. You can create custom comparer by implementing [`IEqualityComparer<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. And for implementing this interface we must implmenet two methods, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

```
public class InfraestructuraComparer: IEqualityComparer<INFRAESTRUCTURA>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether the two INFRAESTRUCTURA are equal.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Equals(INFRAESTRUCTURA firstObj, INFRAESTRUCTURA secondObj)
    {
        if (firstObj == null && secondObj == null)
            return true;

        if (firstObj == null || secondObj == null)
            return false;

        // Your equality logic goes to here
        return firstObj.ID == secondObj.ID;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the hash code for this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public int GetHashCode(INFRAESTRUCTURA obj)
    {
        // Don't compute hash code on null object.
        if (obj == null) return 0;

        unchecked
        {
            var hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 23 + obj.Id.GetHashCode();

            return hash;    
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2, new InfraestructuraComparer());
```

You can also use this comparer in `Except` method, for finding the difference of two sequences.

```
var result = list1.Except(list2, new InfraestructuraComparer());
```

***Additionally:***

From the first point of view you may misunderstood `GetHashCode()`. You can read about this method in many question of StackOverflow. You can read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981298/equals-vs-gethashcode-when-comparing-objects) to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var intersecting = from i1 in l1
                   join i2 in l2
                   on i1.id_infraestructura equals i2.id_infraestructura
                   select i1;
List<INFRAESTRUCTURA> result = intersecting.ToList();
```

If you would override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in `INFRAESTRUCTURA` or provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<INFRAESTRUCTURA>` you could use `Enumerable.Intersect` directly:

```
List<INFRAESTRUCTURA> result = l1.Intersect(l2).ToList();
```

Here's a possible implementation:

```
public class InfrastructureComparer : IEqualityComparer<INFRAESTRUCTURA>
{
    public bool Equals(INFRAESTRUCTURA x, INFRAESTRUCTURA y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.id_infraestructura == y.id_infraestructura;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(INFRAESTRUCTURA obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.id_infraestructura;
    }
}
```

you can use the overloads which take an `IEqualityComparer<T>` like here:

```
List<INFRAESTRUCTURA> result = l1.Intersect(l2, new InfrastructureComparer()).ToList();
```

If you want both objects in the result you could use an anonymous type:

```
var intersecting = from i1 in l1
                   join i2 in l2
                   on i1.id_infraestructura equals i2.id_infraestructura
                   select new { i1, i2 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq Join

```
l1.Join(l2, l => l.id_infraestructura, r => r.id_infraestructura, (l,r) => l.id_infraestructura);
```